# Joint p.d.f stats help

Tags: probability, statistics

$X$ and $Y$ are random variables that have a joint p.d.f., given by $p(x,y)=cx^9y^6$ when $0\le x,y\le 1$ and $p(x,y)=0$ for all other $x,y$. Here $c\ge0$ is a constant, which you should find.

What is the expected value of $Y$? Enter your answer as a decimal.

Comment: This reproduces http://math.stackexchange.com/q/758264/. Either user143888 and user143875 are the same user (and then they are quite rude) or they are following the same class (and then they could join forces).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you integrate $p(x,y)$ over all $x$ and $y$, you should get $1$. This determines $c$.

Then, if you integrate $y p(x,y)$ over all $x$ and $y$, you get the expected value of $Y$.

Alternatively, note that the domain is a product set (in this case, a rectangle with its sides aligned with the x and y axes) and $p(x,y)$ factors into a function of $x$ and $y$,so $X$ and $Y$ are independent and $p(x,y) = p(x) p(y)$. so $p(y) = d y^6$ for $0\leq y \leq 1$ and is $0$ otherwise for some constant $d$ such that $\int_{\mathbb{R}} p(y) dy = \int_0^1 d y^6 dy = 1$. Then, you have $p(y)$ and you can calculate $E[Y] = \int_{\mathbb{R}} y p(y) dy = \int_0^1 y (d y^6) dy$.

Comment: I calculated c as 70, and double integrated to get the answer as 1. But that is incorrect, so I am confused.

Comment: That is the right $c$.